# Should I add the answer from my question to the question it was closed as a duplicate of?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

About a week ago, I asked a CSS question and it got an answer, which I accepted. A little bit later, it was closed as a duplicate. The answer which I got is not one of the answers on the duplicate. Actually all of the answers on the duplicate were among the things I tried in general before I ended up asking the question (none of which worked.)

I know that duplicate questions are "signposts", but I thought that part of their utility was pointing the user to the "main" answer. Since the answer is not there on the linked duplicate, I'm wondering if the correct course of action should be to add an answer there describing this other solution (with a link back to the original to give the original author credit)?

---

<sub>I previously linked to the question I had which was closed as a duplicate, but since it generated a whole bunch of commentary I have removed it. (Find it in the history if you care.) I don't *care* about this specific question/duplicate pair; I want to know if I should be adding the answer I got to the other question mine was a duplicate of. Otherwise if someone has the same problem, it's a case of "your answer is in another castle" since the actual solution (for me) was *not present* on the duplicate.</sub>

Comment: as I commented there, the answer of the duplicate works for you (here is a proof: https://jsfiddle.net/wc9ry8jm/) and has better support than the one you accepted so the duplicate apply to you. No need to do more action, you question is still valid with its answer but is simply closed as duplicate

Comment: ^ and also without the min-width:100%: https://jsfiddle.net/wc9ry8jm/1/ ... an inline-block element has a shrink-to-fit behavior so it apply a *fit-content* width to its content (all this explained in the duplicate)

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that it didn't work. `fit-content` isn't even mentioned on the duplicate, and it _did_ work. Therefore the duplicate -- if it's supposed to have the "answer" -- is incomplete. Also other than IE 11, the [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content) for fit-content seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: The problem is that if I somehow managed to get SO's search to _find_ that duplicate question, it wouldn't have answered my question because the answer was in another castle.

Comment: *Doesn't change the fact that it didn't work* --> I prooved with 2 examples that it does work.

Comment: It didn't work _in my application_. As I indicated in my comment on the question. Maybe it's because my whole set up is nested inside of flexbox, I have no idea -- it's a single component within an SPA I can't go about putting the whole darn website into an example. :-/

Comment: *It didn't work in my application.* --> no one will see *your* application. It works based on the code and the context you provided. I will not judge the duplicate based on something I don't have and no one will do. The duplicate apply to the question you asked, as simple as that. Any context out of your question is out of the scope and you cannot use it as an argument to proove that the duplicate doesn't apply (unless you edit your question to include a full example showing that the code won't work and in this case I might find another better duplicate)

Comment: Look, I don't care about _this question in specific_. The duplicate **does not answer my question**. The answer I did get, _did_. Should I add the answer I _did get_ to the duplicate? That's all I want to know. The answer to my problem -- which maybe someone else will have in the future, who knows -- is _not present_ on the duplicate

Comment: *The duplicate does not answer my question.* --> it **does** (I will insist on this because I have a proof and you don't have any proof) and I don't see why you should add an answer to *your* question into another question. That answer apply to your case and it should be there. Anyone facing the same issue will see it linked to your question AND will also see the duplicate that contain another *working* answer. We don't need the same answer in different places.

Comment: The cleanest solution would be a merge (moderator action), which would move the answers to the new question. Need a bit more clarity that the new answer is worth moving, though. Hopefully this Meta clarifies that

Comment: If the result in your application is different than the one you would get with the code provided in your question, one could argue that your question is incomplete. If you complete the question, it may stop being a dupe (or become a dupe of a different question).

Comment: @Machavity I don't think a merge apply here, both questions are quite different but the solution (with the explanation) apply to both. It should be kept as duplicate because it will trigger different searching results.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just FYI, I mention it because copying an answer is a poor solution (robs the original author of any benefit). Merging is preferable, but only if they're exactly the same question. I wasn't to that point before and I'm not any closer to that point now.

Comment: @Machavity Yes and I am also against copying the solution to the other question because it's not suitable in this case. We should simply do nothing here.

Comment: @Roddy Goodness, the fact that someone is arguing to you, OP, that a given answer answers your question when you say it doesn't, and then is getting frustrated with you about your disagreement, is *utterly* **ridiculous**. You as OP are the only one who gets to decide what answer works best.

Comment: @Roddy As for your present, meta question, if the answer helped you, and it isn't contained in the duplicate, then by all means go add it! You can either provide attribution and post yourself, or provide attribution and post it as a community wiki, either is fine. Unless the answer itself is of low-quality, don't get bogged down by other users trying to tell you what worked best in your own question and usage. Using the knowledge you have to better SO is literally is what the platform is all about.

Comment: I don't thing you're supposed to add an Answer that is identical to any other Answer. It doesn't matter if it's on a duplicate Question or not. See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) which says "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.". cc @zcoop98

Comment: @zcoop98 *You as OP are the only one who gets to decide what answer works best.* --> sorry but this is completely wrong. I will again repeat that I have prooved that my answer works fine, simply proove the opposite if it's not. Saying *not it doesn't work* is far from being enough. It's not up to the OP to decide but the comunity. If the OP decide which answer works then why we allow the community to upvote/downvote or to close question? I have closed a ton of question as duplicate and got a ton of *it doesn't work* comments but this won't change my decision if you cannot *proove* me wrong

Comment: @Temani You misunderstand me- the community does not get to invalidate OP's opinion of which is best. The decision of the community of the best answer, and the decision of OP, are independent decisions, and sometimes may bear zero reference to each other, [this is why accepting an answer exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/776523). You don't get to force someone else to recognize your answer as best or right.

Comment: @Temani You're right though, I misspoke when I said *only one*, that wasn't correct. But OP's designation (accepting an answer) is separate from the community's designation (upvoting), and this is intentional to maintain the opinions of both.

Comment: @Scratte That's fair... I do think there's still a dilemma here though. If a question is commonly asked and has a canonical, and the new dupe actually generates a unique, high-quality answer (though this sounds like an uncommon occurrence), it probably *should* be added to the canonical for future visitors, right?

Comment: @zcoop98 I think only a merge or asking the poster to "move" their Answer will do it though. Unless one is willing to create a similar, but not identical post, and link to the original.

Comment: @zcoop98 The trick in this case is that acceptance is immaterial; the question is closed as a duplicate of another. The OP can accept all they want, but the question remains closed unless the community decides otherwise. Also, the decision of whether to add an answer to a duplicate depends on whether that answer has already been posted (i.e., is unique to the duplicate question) and accurately answers the duplicate question (there may be some subtlety where an answer to the duplicate may not work 100% for the original [e.g., those unwritten externalities already discussed])

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Even on Meta sites, please keep discussion in the comments to a *minimum* and preferably focused on suggestions to improve the question. **If you have an opinion or insight to share, post it as an answer.** Thanks!